# how to capture output of external process in python

Tags: python, stdout, stderr

I am trying to run an external program (in this case just python -V) and capture the standard error in the memory.

It works if I redirect to disk:

```
import sys, os
import subprocess
import tempfile
err = tempfile.mkstemp()
print err[1]
p = subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-V'], stderr=err[0] )
```

but that's not fun. Then I'd need to read that file into memory.

I thought I can create something in-memory that would act like a file using StringIO but this attempt failed:

```
import sys, os
import subprocess
import tempfile
import StringIO

err = StringIO.StringIO()
p = subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-V'], stderr=err )
```

I got:

```
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

ps. Once this works I'll want to capture stdout as well, but I guess that's the same.
ps2. I tried the above on Windows and Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `stderr = subprocess.PIPE`

e.g.:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...,stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
#p.stderr.read() could work too.
```

*note*, for this to work, you need access to the `Popen` object, so you can't really use `subprocess.call` here (you really need `subprocess.Popen`).

Comment: The documentation recommends against that: "Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. " or is that different than subprocess.PIPE that you suggest ?

Comment: @szabgab -- Sorry, I must have been editing while you were commenting.  You can't use `PIPE` with `subprocess.call` (or at least you shouldn't).  You *can* use it with `subprocess.Popen` as I have demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Indeed, my previous comment was made when only the first line of the answer was seen. subprocess.Popen worked nicely. Thanks

Comment: @szabgab -- Sorry.  I suppose I should have taken my time a little more to write a bit more to the answer before hitting the original submit :)

Comment: @mgilson no problem, I just wanted to clarify my comment in a comment in a comment ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess.check_output. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.
```